# How to disable certain SI prefixes in D3 formatter?

Tags: d3.js, format

```
var format = d3.format('s');
format(1000); // 1k, good
format(1000000); //1M, good
format(0.1); // 100m, not necessary, would be better to show 0.1 directly
```

I think most of the time the SI prefix 'm' is not necessary. How can I disable it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in way of customizing the output of `d3.format()` the way you want it. You could, however, define two distinct formats: one for the large numbers including the SI-prefixes, while the other one for the small numbers will omit the prefixes. Wrapping these in a function will give you your custom format function:

```
var formatLarge = d3.format('s');
var formatSmall = d3.format('-.g');
var customFormat = function(val) { 
    return Math.abs(val) < 1 ? formatSmall(val) : formatLarge(val);
};

console.log(customFormat(1000));    // 1k
console.log(customFormat(1000000)); // 1M
console.log(customFormat(0.1));     // 0.1
```